# How to pass selected spinner id to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-toolbar, onitemselectedlistener

Hello I am newbie and developing android application. Pardon my english.

In my App I have MainActivity.java file, in which I am parsing Languagelist Array using json parsing. I send it to next Activity which is Drawer Activity. 
Drawer Activity contains fragments with TabLayout. in this DrawerActivity I have toolbar in which i open spinner and set the arraylist which i get from previous (MainActivity.java). till here everything is ok, but what i want is when user select or change language from toolbar spinner, list of first tab fragment should be refresh. but its not working can any one help me to solve this.

**DrawerActivity.java**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
        bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_LATEST);
        bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new LibraryFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View header = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_music);
        TextView profileName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_library) {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                    bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_LATEST);
                    bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_song) {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                    bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_POPULAR);
                    bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                } /*else if (id == R.id.nav_playlist) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_sound_cound) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_raw_folder) {

                }*/

                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                assert drawer != null;
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.music, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
         spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        rcAdapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(MusicActivity.this,  langList);
         spinner.setAdapter(rcAdapter);


         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 LanguageModel ln=new LanguageModel();
                 ln=langList.get(position);


                 SELECTED_LANGUAGE=ln.getLangid();
                 System.out.println("IF SELECT LA"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                 /*if(SELECTED_LANGUAGE.equals("1"))
                 {
                     SELECTED_LANGUAGE=ln.getLangid();
                     System.out.println("IF SELECT LA"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                     bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                     bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_LATEST);
                     bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                     fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                     final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                     fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                     fragmentTransaction.commit();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     SELECTED_LANGUAGE=ln.getLangid();
                     System.out.println("ELSE SELECT LA"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                     Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                     bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                     bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_LATEST);
                     bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                     fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                     final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                     fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                     fragmentTransaction.commit();
                 }*/


             }

             @Override
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

             }
         });
        /*ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_list_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);*/

        //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        return true;
    }
```

LibraryFragment.java

```
catid=getArguments().getString("frommusic");

        SELECTED_ACTION=getArguments().getString("action");
        SELECTED_LANGUAGE=getArguments().getString("sel_lang");
        System.out.println("in library"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }

    public class CustomFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private  final String TAG = CustomFragmentPageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 3;

        public CustomFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Fragment f1 = new SongFragment();
                    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                    args1.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args1.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    args1.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    f1.setArguments(args1);
                    return f1;
                case 1:

                    Fragment f2 = new PhotoFragment();
                    Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
                    args2.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args2.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    f2.setArguments(args2);
                    return f2;

                case 2:
                    Fragment f3 = new SmsFragment();
                    Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
                    args3.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args3.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    f3.setArguments(args3);
                    return f3;


            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return "Videos";
                case 1:
                    return "Photos";
                case 2:
                    return "SMS";

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

SongFragment.java

```
getActivity().setTitle("Your Status");
        catid=getArguments().getString("fromlibfrag");

        SELECTED_ACTION=getArguments().getString("action");
        SELECTED_LANGUAGE=getArguments().getString("sel_lang");
        System.out.println("in songfragment"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

        vidRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
         linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        vidRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        vidRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        VIDEO_LIST_URL= WebUrls.WEB_URL+"GetVideos&language_id="+SELECTED_LANGUAGE+"&action="+SELECTED_ACTION+"&category_id="+catid;

        System.out.println("FINAL URL"+VIDEO_LIST_URL);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        makeJsonArrayRequestvideos();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one public method in `LibraryFragment.java`
name it as `updateData()` // pas the arguments you want to use.

Now in

`DrawerActivity.java` make
    `LibraryFragment` instance public

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_library) {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                    bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_LATEST);
                    bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    mLibraryFragment= new LibraryFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_song) {
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("frommusic", CAT_ID);
                    bundle.putString("action", DRAWER_ACTION_POPULAR);
                    bundle.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragment = new LibraryFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                } /*else if (id == R.id.nav_playlist) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_sound_cound) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_raw_folder) {

                }*/

                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container_wrapper, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                assert drawer != null;
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                 LanguageModel ln=new LanguageModel();
                 ln=langList.get(position);


                 SELECTED_LANGUAGE=ln.getLangid();
                 System.out.println("IF SELECT LA"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                 if(mLibraryFragment!=null){
                      mLibraryFragment.updateData()//pass the param 
                you want upate in library fragment.
               }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Comment: Which thing you not got ?

Comment: where to create method ? and what to write in spinner listener?